# For displaying maps in ios should we use ArcGIS Apis or Google Map APIs?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, google-maps, arcgis

Advantages and disadvantages of ArcGIS/Google Map APIS?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with Google Maps APIS, since it's the standard way of doing this. You will have more documentation and more examples to help you. But with the release of the iOS 6, if I were you, I would wait to check the new "goodies". :)